# 4 solutions to leetcode 202. Happy Number have almost same performance

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, comparative-review

I am working on an easy math question Happy number [Happy Number - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/happy-number/)

> 202. Happy Number
>
> Write an algorithm to determine if a number is "happy".
>
> A happy number is a number defined by the following process: Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1. Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy numbers.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> Input: 19
> Output: true
> Explanation: 
> 1² + 9² = 82
> 8² + 2² = 68
> 6² + 8² = 100
> 1² + 0² + 0² = 1
> ```

My solutions

- Solution 1, 28ms 12.1mb

  - string operations

```py
class Solution1:
    def isHappy(self, n):
        s = set()
        while n != 1:
            if n in s: return False
            s.add(n)
            n = sum([int(i) ** 2 for i in str(n)])
        else:
            return True
```

- Solution 2,  24ms, 12.3mb

```py
class Solution2:
    def isHappy(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        s = set()
        while n != 1:
            if n in s: return False
            s.add(n)

            _sum = 0
            while n:
                _sum += (n % 10) ** 2
                n //= 10
            n = _sum

        return n == 1
```

- Solution 3  the save as solution 2 minor changes  (24ms, 12.3mb)

```py
class Solution3:
    def isHappy(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        s = set()
        while n:
            if 1 in s:
                return True
            if n in s:
                return False
            s.add(n)
            _sum = 0
            while n:
                _sum += (n%10)**2 #leave unit digit
                n //= 10 #remvoe unit digit 
            n = _sum
```

- Solution 4 without extra space(24ms, 12.3mb)

```py
class Solution4:
    def isHappy(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        while n != 1 and n != 4:
            _sum = 0
            while n :
                _sum += (n % 10) * (n % 10)
                n //= 10
            n = _sum

        return n == 1
```

TestCase

```
class MyCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.solution = Solution3()

    def test_1(self):
        n = 19
        check = self.solution.isHappy(n)
        self.assertTrue(check)
```

It's interesting that the last 3 solutions shared the same performance, though try best possibility to improve it.

Comment: In general, you should never be using a benchmark that takes less than a second. Timings below that are way too variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution #2:

```
class Solution2:
    def isHappy(self, n):
        # ...
        while n != 1:
            if n in s: return False
            # ...

    return n == 1
```

You are looping while `n != 1`, without any `break` statements. There is no need to test `n == 1` at the return statement at the end.  Just `return True`.

---

Solution #3 returns `None` if 0 is given as input, instead of returning `True` or `False`.

---

Solution #4 becomes an endless loop if 0 is given as input.

Are there any other stopping conditions other that `n == 0`, `n == 1` or `n == 4`?  It isn't clear that all unhappy numbers result in a loop containing the value `4`, so the validity of this approach is in question.

**Update**: Actually [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number#Sequence_behavior) provides a clear argument that unhappy numbers will arrive in a loop containing the value `4`, so this approach is valid, but should included a comment with a link to that proof.

---

In all your solutions, your loop is testing at least two conditions, such as both `n != 1` and `n is s`.  Why not initialize `s` to contain a `1` (or even just leave it as an empty set), and then only test `n in s`.  No special cases.

```
def is_happy(n):
    s = { 1 }

    while n not in s:
        s.add(n)
        n = sum(i * i for i in map(int, str(n)))

    return n == 1
```

**Update**:

Since [Wikipedea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number#Sequence_behavior) has *proof* that all positive unhappy numbers end in the sequence `4 → 16 → 37 → 58 → 89 → 145 → 42 → 20 → 4 → ...`, and happy numbers end in the sequence `1 → 1 → ...`, you can create a set of these termination values (including `0 → 0 → ...`), and no longer needed to maintain the set of "seen" values.  By using all numbers in the unhappy loop, we can terminate the search up to 8 iterations earlier over just checking for `n == 1` and `n == 4`.

```
def is_happy(num):
    # See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number#Sequence_behavior
    terminal = { 0, 1, 4, 16, 20, 37, 42, 58, 89, 145 }

    while num not in terminal:
        num = sum(i * i for i in map(int, str(num)))

    return n == 1
```

---

Finally:

- follow the [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) standards (avoid mixedCase function/method names),
- [Stop writing classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)!